# Bootstrap.css not referred in register.html page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

**Doubts in twitter bootstrap**

1.when inspecting the register.html in chrome browser,which not refereed bootstrap.css instead its refereeing less files.

2.I dont have an idea about what is less files but when I seeing in that dist folder ,there is no less folder but its only coming on inspecting the element in browser? could you please clear me about this?

grid system column with offsetting not working

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">.col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4</div>
</div>
```

col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 not moving to the right side.col-md-offset-4 not referred this column properly.- please help me out

```
    <!Doctype Html>
<html charset='UTF-8'>
        <head>

            <link  href="../bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="../Css/Custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        </head>
            <body>
                <img  class="bg-img img-responsive"
                     src="../image/SPRING.jpg"  alt="bg-image"  
                     height="188" >
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="panel panel-default center-block">
                        <div class="panel-body center-block">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <label>Profile</label>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit pull-right"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <img src="../Image/Saraswathi.jpg" alt="profile-pic" class="img-circle">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="text-left">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        Atmansan</div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        San1234</div>
                                </span>
                                <span class="text-center">
                                    <span class="col-md-2">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                                <span class="text-right">
                                    <span class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>san@gmail.com</label>
                                        <label>8000000000</label>
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
<script src="../bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
type="text/js"></script>
<script src="../jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/jquery"></script>    
           </body>

</html>
```

Comment: post your html's `head` section code too

Comment: I have added my index.html page.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

Please add your index.html file.  Bootstrap probably has a css mapping, making you see the source `.less` files instead of the compiled `.css` file when you inspect the `register.html` in your browser

EDIT: after questioner provided `index.html`:
I still think it is a mapping inside the `bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css` file, directing you to your `.less` file. Less is a CSS pre-processor, and you can learn more about it at [less.org](http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: Yes added my index.html page